# How to switch to normal wifi mode to access-point mode ESP8266

Tags: arduino, esp8266, wifi, access-point

I am using ESP8266-12 wifi module for accessing my home wifi network to control lights. For uploading new firmware(OTA: Over the Air) update, I want to use ESP8266's hotspot AccessPoint because after changing the password of my wifi network, I will not able to do that. This is my Arduino code:

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <ESP8266mDNS.h>
#include <ArduinoOTA.h>
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>

//ssid and password of your wifi network
const char* ssid = "wifi_ssid";
const char* password = "wifi_password";

//ssid and password to connect to local hotspot of ESP8266
const char *esp_ssid = "your_desired_ssid";
const char *esp_password = "your_desired_password";

IPAddress ip(192, 168, 1, xx); // where xx is the desired IP Address
IPAddress gateway(192, 168, 1, 254); // set gateway to match your wifi network
IPAddress subnet(255, 255, 255, 0); // set subnet mask to match your wifi network

ESP8266WebServer server(80);
int status = LOW;
const int pin = 5;

const char* serverIndex = "<form method='POST' action='/update' enctype='multipart/form-data'><input type='file' name='update'><input type='submit' value='Update'></form>";

//Authorization username and password before updating firmware
const char* www_username = "admin";
const char* www_password = "esp8266";

void connectToWifi() {
  Serial.print("Connecting to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);

  WiFi.config(ip, gateway, subnet);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  while(WiFi.waitForConnectResult() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
    //ESP.restart();
  }
  Serial.print("WiFi connected to ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
}

void createAccessPoint() {
  Serial.println("Configuring access point for wifi network *your_desired_ssid*...");
  WiFi.softAP(esp_ssid, esp_password);
  IPAddress accessIP = WiFi.softAPIP();
  Serial.print("ESP AccessPoint IP address: ");
  Serial.println(accessIP);
  /* Go to http://192.168.4.1 in a web browser
   * connected to this access point to see it.
   */
}

void serverResponse(){
  server.sendHeader("Connection", "close");
  server.sendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  server.send(200, "text/plain", String(status));
}


void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  pinMode(pin, OUTPUT);
  connectToWifi();
  ArduinoOTA.begin();
  server.on("/fupdate", [](){
    if(server.authenticate(www_username, www_password)){
      createAccessPoint();
      server.sendHeader("Connection", "close");
      server.sendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
      server.send(200, "text/html", serverIndex);
    }
    else{
       return server.requestAuthentication();
    }

  });
  server.on("/status", [](){
    serverResponse();
  });
  server.on("/on", [](){
    status = HIGH;
    serverResponse();
  });
  server.on("/off", [](){
    status = LOW;
    serverResponse();
  });
  server.on("/update", HTTP_POST, [](){
      server.sendHeader("Connection", "close");
      server.sendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
      server.send(200, "text/plain", (Update.hasError())?"FAIL":"OK");
      ESP.restart();
    },[](){
      HTTPUpload upload = server.upload();
      if(upload.status == UPLOAD_FILE_START){
        Serial.setDebugOutput(true);
        WiFiUDP::stopAll();
        Serial.printf("Update: %s\n", upload.filename.c_str());
        uint32_t maxSketchSpace = (ESP.getFreeSketchSpace() - 0x1000) & 0xFFFFF000;
        if(!Update.begin(maxSketchSpace)){//start with max available size
          Update.printError(Serial);
        }
      } else if(upload.status == UPLOAD_FILE_WRITE){
        if(Update.write(upload.buf, upload.currentSize) != upload.currentSize){
          Update.printError(Serial);
        }
      } else if(upload.status == UPLOAD_FILE_END){
        if(Update.end(true)){ //true to set the size to the current progress
          Serial.printf("Update Success: %u\nRebooting...\n", upload.totalSize);
        } else {
          Update.printError(Serial);
        }
        Serial.setDebugOutput(false);
      }
      yield();
    });
  server.begin();
  MDNS.addService("http", "tcp", 80);

  Serial.print("Open http://");
  Serial.print(WiFi.localIP());
  Serial.println("/ in your browser to see it working");
}

void loop() {
  digitalWrite(pin, status);
  ArduinoOTA.handle();
  server.handleClient();
  delay(1);
}
```

I have a simple WifiWebServer which handles the requests. When I send `/fupdate` request, ESP module should create hotspot and I can connect my computer through the access-point to update firmware. For updating firmware I have set authorization. If authorization will be done only T can upload the new firmware. **But my ESP8266 module is creating the hotspot before sending** `/fupdate` **request or authorization. It's enabling hotspot when I am giving power. Can someone how to resolve this problem?

Comment: Must be resolved with below comments

Answer (score 7):

Put these lines to the top of the function called **connectToWifi()** :

```
  WiFi.softAPdisconnect();
  WiFi.disconnect();
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  delay(100);
```

ESP's WiFi module stores its own config on chip and he expects to overwrite it clearly. Do not make him to try something common, define configs clearly and stop unrelated previous operations.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you never close the Access Point. You probably omitted that part here but make sure that after you update the firmware you close the A.P. properly. If you run the code just like this , probably would work well the first time  but once you run the "/fupdate" command it'll maintain the  A.P. forever, and eventually would crash when you run "/fupdate" for the second time.

So you should check the status before calling "createAccessPoint" also, because if its already created the software could fail.